# Pandas Append is adding new row without Index number

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

This is what I'm trying to accomplish with my code: I have a current csv file with tennis player names, and I want to add new players to it once they show in the rankings. My script goes through the rankings and creates an array, then imports the names from the csv file. It is supposed to see which names are not in the latter, and then extract online data for those names. Then, I just want the new rows to be appended at the end of that old CSV file. My issue is that the new row is being indexed with the Player's name rather than following the index of the old file. Any ideas why that's happening? Also why is an unnamed column being added?

```
def get_all_players():

    # imports names of players currently in the atp rankings
    current_atp_ranking = check_atp_rankings()
    current_player_list = current_atp_ranking['Player']

    # clean up names in case of white spaces
    for i in range(0, len(current_player_list)):
        current_player_list[i] = current_player_list[i].strip()

    # reads the main file and makes a dataframe out of it
    current_file = 'ATP_stats_new.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(current_file)

    # gets all the names within the main file to see which current ones aren't there
    names_on_file = list(df['Player'])
    # cleans up in case of any white spaces
    for i in range(0, len(names_on_file)):
        names_on_file[i] = names_on_file[i].strip()

    # Removing Nadal for testing purposes
    names_on_file.remove("Rafael Nadal")

    # creating a list of players in current_players_list but not in names_on_file
    new_player_list = [x for x in current_player_list if x not in names_on_file]

    # loop through new_player_list
    for player in new_player_list:

        # delay to avoid stopping
        time.sleep(2)

        # finding the player's atp link for profile based on their name
        atp_link = current_atp_ranking.loc[current_atp_ranking['Player'] == player, 'ATP_Link']
        atp_link = atp_link.iloc[0]

        # make a basic dictionary with just the player's name and link
        player_dict = [{'Name': player, 'ATP_Link': atp_link}]

        # enter the new dictionary into the existing main file
        df.append(player_dict, ignore_index=True)

    # print dataframe to see how it looks before exporting
    print(df)

    # export dataframe into current file
    df.to_csv(current_file)
```

This is what the file looks like at first:

```
      Unnamed: 0            Player  ...                         Coach Turned_Pro
0              0    Novak Djokovic  ...                           NaN        NaN
1              1      Rafael Nadal  ...   Carlos Moya, Francisco Roig     2001.0
2              2     Roger Federer  ...  Ivan Ljubicic, Severin Luthi     1998.0
3              3   Daniil Medvedev  ...                           NaN        NaN
4              4     Dominic Thiem  ...                           NaN        NaN
...          ...               ...  ...                           ...        ...
1976        1976      Brian Bencic  ...                           NaN        NaN
1977        1977  Boruch Skierkier  ...                           NaN        NaN
1978        1978      Majed Kilani  ...                           NaN        NaN
1979        1979   Quentin Gueydan  ...                           NaN        NaN
1980        1980     Preston Brown  ...                           NaN        NaN
```

And this is what the new row looks like:

```
1977              1977.0  ...        NaN
1978              1978.0  ...        NaN
1979              1979.0  ...        NaN
1980              1980.0  ...        NaN
Rafael Nadal         NaN  ...       2001
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Please rephrase the problem with a minimal working example of your problem - having to go through all of your application and code is not useful and will be noise for further users that could benefit from your question but not find it.

Comment: @Arnaud just trimmed it down to the basics. I'm looking for a way to add the new row so it is indexed with the 1981 number instead of with "Rafael Nadal". Also looking for a way to not have this Unnamed column added

Answer (score 0):

There are critical parts of your code missing that are necessary to answer the question precisely.   Two thoughts based on what you posted:

**Importing Your CSV File**

Your previous csv file was probably saved with the index.  Make sure the csv file contents does not have the dataframe index when you last used it in the first csv column.  When you save do the following:

```
file.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

When you load the file like this;

```
pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
```

it will automatically assigned the index number and there won't be a duplicate column.

**Misordering of Columns**

Not sure what info in what order `atp_link` is pulling in.  From what you provided it looks like it is returning two columns:  "Coach" and "Turning Pro".

I would recommend creating a list (not a dict) for each new player you want to add after you pull the info from `atp_link`.  So if you are adding Nadal, You create an info list from the information *for each new player*.  Nadal's info list would look like this:

```
info_list = ['Rafael Nadal', '','2001']
```

Then you append the list to the dataframe like this:

```
df.loc[len(df),:] = info_list
```

Hope this helps.